# Variation unable to trigger update all targets

Tags: 2013, variations, update

when I am trying to trigger the update all targets by selecting multiple items in a library, I get this message "Failed to submit the update for the selected items." I currently have Full Control permission on the site.

When I am using a site administrator account, it actually worked. Is this really a limitation, my understanding is that if it is available, it should be able to be used, else the control will be disabled.

If I open a specific page, the update all targets do work. But it will be painful for moderator to do one page at a time.

[image: Failed to update all targets for regular users]

Comment: I think list in target site is not exist.